# SQL Exception Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, pagination, spring-jdbc

I upgraded "spring-boot-starter-parent" to version 1.5.4.RELEASE and it started giving me sql exception when I request to fetch next page of my search result using HATEOAS link. It works perfectly fine with version 1.4.0.RELEASE. What should I change to make my api compatible for both the versions or at least upgraded one?

Exception I get is:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na].....`